# Look up to find exact match based on the given date

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, offset

All,

I have three columns in a table -- Candidate number (that can be duplicate), last checked in date, and his score in the test on a date.

I need a formula that looks up the last prior date based on the candidate number and a date that I specify in a cell.

I tried `MAX((Sheet2!$C$6:$C$45<=G$6)*Sheet2!$C$6:$C$45)` to get the prior date, but unable to integrate how to restrict it to check only based on a candidate number.

My output looks like in cell A1 (Candidate number), and in cell B1 (Date I want to check)

Output:

`"Candidate Number" 
 "Last checkin date prior to the specified date"
 "Marks on that output date"`

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

This formula will give you the last date before the date in B1, where the candidatenumber is the number in A1. I assume that the candidatenumbers are in column A and the dates are in column B, in rows 6 to 45.

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet2!A6:A45=A1,IF(Sheet2!B6:B45<B1,Sheet2!B6:B45)))
```

It's an array-formula, so confirm with ctrl-shift-enter

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX(IF` combination

Don't forget to close your formula with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`